# I am facing JDBC issue while I run them Apache tomcat as a windows service

Tags: tomcat7

My application is working as expected while I run them manually by using startup.bat file but I am facing JDBC issue while I run the tomcat as a windows service. My tomcat version is 7.0.91 and OS is windows 2016